# Whole PC suddenly running slowly

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, graphics-card, performance

I recently played a game requiring a ton of VRAM, which sometimes causes crashes. Which until now has been fine, the most recent crash caused my PC to run insanely slow, opening any applications, browser tabs, turning on my PC etc. has been significantly been affected.

I've tried a full AV scan with Avira and Trend Micro (currently attempting with ESET) as well as a Malwarebytes scan, but have found nothing.

Besides this I've attempted to check my disks for errors again with no errors. What could possibly be wrong, and how do I fix it? Please do tell me if there's anything I'd need to troubleshoot, and I'll be happy to provide the information provided.

My current PC specs are as follows:

CPU: Intel Core i7 7700K

GPU: GeForce GTX 1070

RAM: Corsair Vengeance 16GB

PSU: EVGA Nex 650G

Motherboard: ASUS Strix Z270E

Bootdisk: NVMe Samsung 960

HDD: Seagate Barracuda 1TB

I hope there's an easy solution to this, thanks!

EDIT: Sometimes tabs work at normal speed, and some programs as well, although very rarely

EDIT2: Once I crash an error message pops up from the game saying it's a memory issue causing it to crash, perhaps thats the problem too? Although I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Temperatures are normal as well

Comment: How much free space do you have on the OS partition?

Comment: 92GB, that shouldnt be a problem, other HDD has 756GB

Comment: Most of the hardware besides PSU and HDD is pretty new (less than 2 months old), so I don't see how any of them could be a problem, could it be a problem with the OS? If so what can I do to avoid a reinstall of OS?

Comment: What does Task Manager tell you in the performance and process tabs?  Are any of your system resources (RAM, CPU, disk) being heavily accessed?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: do you over or underclock the CPU and change Volatge settings? if yes, undo this.

Comment: Did you check the SSD with Samsung Magician?

Comment: I had it fixed with a simple troubleshoot through Windows "Hardware and Devices" troubleshooting, although it has happened again now. I have no changes to CPU clock/voltage, and I have not checked Samsung Magician, I'll make an attempt at that and come back later.

EDIT: The troubleshoot fixing it earlier, isn't working now.